# try-catch in method having return object T

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have a  method in c#, in which it return an object! I need to use a try catch here

this is my method

```
public T FromBinary()
{
    T obj;
    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(this.serializeFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            obj=(T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Cannot convert Binary to object", e.Message + "Trace" + e.StackTrace);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

But i am getting an error

> Use of unassigned local variable 'obj'.

How can I use try catch in method having return object T?

Comment: You can assign null to obj initially like `T obj = null;`

Comment: @yogi.. Soryy now geting error `Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(T)' `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it to `T obj = default(T);`.

Answer (score 4):

you have to write `T obj = default(T);` to assign the variable with a initial value

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are trying to let your method return the object before it has been assigned a value(if the code throws an exception).

the solution is to set your declaration to:

```
T obj = Default(T);
```

You should also make it a try-catch-finally so that you allways return the object and close the file stream like this:

```
}//end of catch block
finnally{
stream.Close();
return obj;
}
}//end of method
```